# basic java Main method and update

Tags: java, swing, program-entry-point

Im new to pure java after been coding in javabased processing ([processing.org](http://processing.org)) a lot. In processing you have a setup method (the constructor) and a draw method in the main class.

The draw method loops over and over again untill you close the program. In draw i run my methods from other classes.

How do I do this in java? For example in this code below for getting the counter to count?

```
public class Testing3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        System.out.println("c = " + c.getCount());
    }
}
```

And the class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private int value;

    public MyClass() {

    }

    public void setCount(int startV) {
        value = startV;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        value++;
        int counter = value % 10;
        return counter;
    }
}
```

I know I of course can put the printmessage in a while loop and loop it that way but I guess there are other ways?

I have also been using swing a bit through the GUI builder in netbeans. There I cannot reach my objects within the main method, getting the *"non static variable cannot be referenced from a static content"*. only through functions like the one below. But what if I want to get my counter without pushing on a button i created in the builder etc?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  {}
```

I know its a newby question but Im a bit confused.

Comment: In core java you actually really have to do this with a loop. But there are Timer-classes in JavaFX which trigger an event in a set interval. Then your eventhandler can run code everytime these events are triggered.

Comment: To have something occur on a set interval (either once or repeated) in Swing, us a [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). `getting the "non static variable` I recommend posting an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand your question (assuming there's only one question) , but I think this is what you're looking for

```
      import java.awt.FlowLayout;
      import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
      import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
      import javax.swing.JButton;
      import javax.swing.JFrame;
      import javax.swing.JLabel;

      class Listener implements ActionListener{
          int n;
          JLabel label;
          public Listener(int n,JLabel label){
              this.n=n;
              this.label=label;
          }
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              n++;
              label.setText(""+n);      
          }
      }

      public class SwingTest {
          public static void main(String[] args) {
              int n=0;
              JFrame frame= new JFrame("My First JAVA SWING App");
              frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
              JLabel label=new JLabel("value here");
              JButton button=new JButton("click!!!");
              button.addActionListener(new Listener(n,label));
              frame.add(button);
              frame.add(label);
              frame.setSize(200, 100);
              frame.setVisible(true);
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          }
      }
```

this should be on a file called SwingTest.java

Comment: thanks. I have no problems running and updating with a button. :-) I was a bit confused how I could update the GUI for example if I got a counter that will display the ticking if Im not creating the ticking with a button. But I guess  javax.swing.Timer would help. Need to have a look there.